# How to do snapshot testing using protobuf3 text messages?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Can someone let me know if there is any library or extension available for doing snapshot testing using protobuf text messages?

Something similar to what the below libraries do

1. [json-snapshot](https://json-snapshot.github.io/)
2. [jest framework](https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing)

Language - Java

Answer (score 1):

[selfie](https://selfie.dev/jvm) is snapshot testing available on JVM.

- it can do snapshots on disk or as [inline literals](https://selfie.dev/jvm#literal)
- it garbage-collects unused disk snapshots [automatically](https://github.com/diffplug/selfie/blob/main/selfie-runner-junit5/src/main/kotlin/com/diffplug/selfie/junit5/SelfieGC.kt)
- easy to [control read/write](https://selfie.dev/jvm/get-started#quickstart) without any CLI flags, run
- (advanced) you can snapshot multiple facets of an entity, and then assert some on disk and others inline to [tell a story](https://selfie.dev/jvm/advanced#harmonizing-disk-and-inline-literals)

Comment: Does it understand proto messages? I mean is it possible to skip certain fields in proto messages from snapshotting by declaring it somehow in some config or may be in proto definition by using some custom tags?

Comment: You can make it understand proto messages and skip certain fields using `Camera`. https://selfie.dev/jvm/advanced